# Making dungeon map generator: stuck with doors

Tags: javascript, maps, path-finding, 2d-games

I made a primitive dungeon generator (on pure JavaScript) that creates nearby rooms. Link to a working piece of code is in the bottom of post.

Now I am stuck: I need to make a good system of doors and passages between rooms, but I find it difficult to come up with a suitable algorithm. Technically, there is no problem: it's easy to make holes in the walls and even make sure that all parts of the dungeon are connected to each other.

The problem is to find a suitable idea for connecting rooms. Screw all possible connections and close excess? Choose a large room and pull a few corridors out of it, and then connect the remaining rooms to the common system? Start from a corner and move chaotically until all rooms are connected?

I will be very grateful for any idea or advice.

**Update**. Question is solved. With the help of raul.vila it was possible to bring the algorithm to the working state. Now the generator does the minimum number of doors necessary to get to each room, and then creates several additional doors to improve the connectivity of the dungeon.

Old code: https://jsfiddle.net/Gerasim/f2a8ujpy/3/

Final code: https://jsfiddle.net/Gerasim/f2a8ujpy/29/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const DWIDTH = 32; // Dungeon width
const DHEIGHT = 32; // Dungeon height
const ROOMINTERVAL = 8; // Room density (3+)
const MINROOM = 3; // Min room size. Must be ROOMINTERVAL - 2 or bigger
const EXTRADOORS = 5; // Additional doors for better connectivity

arrayInstruments();
genDungeon();
showDungeon();


// Displays primitive map of the dungeon
function showDungeon() {
  for (var x = 0; x < DWIDTH; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < DHEIGHT; y++) {
      switch (dungeon[x][y]) {
        case 0:
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
          ctx.rect(x * 20, y * 20, 18, 18);
          ctx.fill();
          break;
        case 1:
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.rect(x * 20, y * 20, 18, 18);
          ctx.fill();
          break;
        case 2:
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.fillStyle = "black";
          ctx.rect(x * 20 + 1, y * 20 + 1, 16, 16);
          ctx.rect(x * 20 + 12, y * 20 + 6, 2, 4);
          ctx.stroke();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}


// Generates dungeon of rooms and doors
function genDungeon() {

  // Fill full dungeon with walls
  dungeon = new Array();
  dungeon.dup(1, 0, 0, DWIDTH, DHEIGHT);

  // Create random seeds of growth in size MINROOM x MINROOM
  var seeds = new Array();
  while (true) {
    var free = dungeon.biggestFree(0, 0, 0, DWIDTH, DHEIGHT);
    if (free.biggest < ROOMINTERVAL) {
      break;
    } else {
      roomX = free.x + 1 + rnd(free.biggest - 1 - MINROOM);
      roomY = free.y + 1 + rnd(free.biggest - 1 - MINROOM);
      dungeon.dup(0, roomX, roomY, MINROOM, MINROOM);
      seeds.push({
        x: roomX,
        y: roomY,
        width: MINROOM,
        height: MINROOM,
        delete: "no"
      });
    }
  }

  var rooms = [];

  // Now we have seeds of growth in array rooms.
  // Lets try to expand seeds by moving their walls
  while (seeds.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < seeds.length; i++) {
      // Determine the directions in which the room can grow 
      var dirs = [];
      if (seeds[i].x >= 2 && dungeon.freeRect(0, seeds[i].x - 2, seeds[i].y - 1, 1, seeds[i].height + 2)) {
        dirs.push('left');
      }
      if (seeds[i].x + seeds[i].width < DWIDTH - 1 && dungeon.freeRect(0, seeds[i].x + seeds[i].width + 1, seeds[i].y - 1, 1, seeds[i].height + 2)) {
        dirs.push('right');
      }
      if (seeds[i].y >= 2 && dungeon.freeRect(0, seeds[i].x - 1, seeds[i].y - 2, seeds[i].width + 2, 1)) {
        dirs.push('up');
      }
      if (seeds[i].y + seeds[i].height < DHEIGHT - 1 && dungeon.freeRect(0, seeds[i].x - 1, seeds[i].y + seeds[i].height + 1, seeds[i].width + 2, 1)) {
        dirs.push('down');
      }

      // Now expand room in random direction
      if (dirs.length > 0) {
        dirs.shuffle();
        if (dirs[0] == 'left') {
          dungeon.dup(0, seeds[i].x - 1, seeds[i].y, 1, seeds[i].height);
          seeds[i].x--;
          seeds[i].width++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'right') {
          dungeon.dup(0, seeds[i].x + seeds[i].width, seeds[i].y, 1, seeds[i].height);
          seeds[i].width++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'up') {
          dungeon.dup(0, seeds[i].x, seeds[i].y - 1, seeds[i].width, 1);
          seeds[i].y--;
          seeds[i].height++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'down') {
          dungeon.dup(0, seeds[i].x, seeds[i].y + seeds[i].height, seeds[i].width, 1);
          seeds[i].height++;
        }
      } else {
        seeds[i].delete = "yes";
        rooms.push(seeds[i]);
      }
      seeds = seeds.filter(o => o.delete == "no");
    }
  }

  // Make required doors
  var startRoom = rooms[0];
  startRoom.parentRoom = startRoom;
  connectToOtherRooms(rooms, startRoom);

  // Make extra doors
  var i = EXTRADOORS;
  var limiter = 1000; // protection from an infinite loop
  while (i > 0 && limiter > 0) {
    if (connectToRandom(rooms)) {
      i--;
    }
    limiter--;
  }
}

// Makes tree of rooms
function connectToOtherRooms(rooms, currentRoom) {
  var adyacentRoom = connectToAdyacent(rooms, currentRoom);
  if (adyacentRoom) {
    connectToOtherRooms(rooms, adyacentRoom);
  } else {
    if (currentRoom.parentRoom == currentRoom) {
      return;
    } else {
      connectToOtherRooms(rooms, currentRoom.parentRoom);
    }
  }
}

// Makes door to the adyacent room
function connectToAdyacent(rooms, room) {
  var nonVisitedRooms = rooms.filter(o => o != room && !o.parentRoom);
  for (var i = 0; i < nonVisitedRooms.length; i++) {
    var nonVisitedRoom = nonVisitedRooms[i];
    if (makeDoor(room, nonVisitedRoom)) {
      nonVisitedRoom.parentRoom = room;
      return nonVisitedRoom;
    }
  }
}


// Makes door to the random room nearby
function connectToRandom(allRooms) {
  var room = rnd(allRooms.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < allRooms.length; i++) {
    if (makeDoor(allRooms[room], allRooms[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


// Makes door between two rooms
function makeDoor(room1, room2) {
  var walls = commonWalls(room1, room2);
  if (walls && !foundDoor(walls)) {
    walls.shuffle();
    dungeon[walls[0].x][walls[0].y] = 2;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


// Checks if there is a door in walls already to avoid double doors
function foundDoor(walls) {
  for (var i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
    if (dungeon[walls[i].x][walls[i].y] > 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


// Returns array of cells between two rooms (if any)
function commonWalls(room1, room2) {
  var walls = new Array();
  var per1 = perimeter(room1);
  var per2 = perimeter(room2);
  for (var i = 0; i < per1.length; i++) {
    var common = per2.filter(o => o.x == per1[i].x && o.y == per1[i].y);
    if (common.length > 0) {
      walls.push(common[0]);
    }
  }
  if (walls.length > 0) {
    return walls;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


// Returns array of cells on the external perimeter of room
// Corner cells are excluded, since the door is not made there
function perimeter(room) {
  var per = new Array();
  for (x = room.x; x < room.x + room.width; x++) {
    per.push({
      x: x,
      y: room.y - 1
    });
    per.push({
      x: x,
      y: room.y + room.height
    });
  }
  for (y = room.y; y < room.y + room.height; y++) {
    per.push({
      x: room.x - 1,
      y: y
    });
    per.push({
      x: room.x + room.width,
      y: y
    });
  }
  return per;
}


// rnd(4): returns 0, 1, 2 or 3
function rnd(ceil) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * ceil);
}


// Several instruments that I need to work with arrays
function arrayInstruments() {

  // Shuffles array in random order
  Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var j, temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      j = rnd(this.length);
      temp = this[i];
      this[i] = this[j];
      this[j] = temp;
    }
    return (this);
  }

  // Fills rectangle in 2D-array with filler
  Array.prototype.dup = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    for (var x = startX; x < startX + lengthX; x++) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this[x])) {
        this[x] = new Array();
      }
      for (var y = startY; y < startY + lengthY; y++) {
        this[x][y] = filler;
      }
    }
  }


  // Checks whether the specified area of the two-dimensional array is free of filler
  // If it is free, it returns true
  Array.prototype.freeRect = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    for (var x = startX; x < startX + lengthX; x++) {
      for (var y = startY; y < startY + lengthY; y++) {
        if (this[x][y] == filler) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }


  // Returns the coordinates of the largest empty square.
  // If there are several equally large empty squares, returns the coordinates of the random
  Array.prototype.biggestFree = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    var found = new Array();
    for (biggest = Math.min(lengthX, lengthY); biggest > 0; biggest--) {
      for (var x = startX; x <= startX + lengthX - biggest; x++) {
        for (var y = startY; y <= startY + lengthY - biggest; y++) {
          if (this.freeRect(filler, x, y, biggest, biggest)) {
            found.push({
              x: x,
              y: y
            });
          }
        }
      }
      if (found.length > 0) {
        found.shuffle();
        return {
          biggest: biggest,
          x: found[0].x,
          y: found[0].y
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to describe an algorithm. The idea is to create a tree starting from a random room and visiting all rooms going from the current room to a non-visited adyacent one.

This should work:

1. create `currentRoom` variable pointing to a random initial room
2. set `currentRoom.parentRoom = currentRoom`, a trick to identify the initial room
3. with `currentRoom`:

   31. list adyacents non-visited rooms (`adyNonVisRooms`), you can check if a room has a `parentRoom` property defined to see if it has been visited
   32. if `adyNonVisRooms.length > 0`:

       321. set `nextRoom = adyNonVisRooms[0]` (you can get a random room for a non-deterministic result)
       322. connect `currentRoom` with `nextRoom` adding a door
       323. set `nextRoom.parentRoom = currentRoom`
       324. set `currentRoom = nextRoom`
       325. go to 3
   33. if `adyNonVisRooms.length == 0`:

       331. if `currentRoom == currentRoom.parentRoom`:

            3331. list adyacents non-visited rooms (`adyNonVisRooms`)
            3332. if `adyNonVisRooms.length > 0`: goto 321
            3333. if `adyNonVisRooms.length == 0`: EXIT
       332. if `currentRoom != currentRoom.parentRoom`:

            3321. set `currentRoom = currentRoom.parentRoom`
            3322. go to 3

I have a working version, you will need to work a bit to get random room positions (functions `connectIfOnTop` and `connectIfOnRight`): [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/urcg8033/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const DWIDTH = 32; // Dungeon width
const DHEIGHT = 32; // Dungeon height
const ROOMINTERVAL = 8; // Room density (3+)
const MINROOM = 2; // Min room size. Must be ROOMINTERVAL - 2 or bigger

arrayInstruments();
genDungeon();
showDungeon();

function showDungeon() {
  for (var x = 0; x < DWIDTH; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < DHEIGHT; y++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x * 20, y * 20, 18, 18);
      if (dungeon[x][y] == 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
      }
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}

function genDungeon() {

  // Fill dungeon with walls
  dungeon = new Array();
  dungeon.dup(1, 0, 0, DWIDTH, DHEIGHT);

  // Create random seeds of growth in size MINROOM x MINROOM
  var rooms = new Array();
  while (true) {
    var free = dungeon.biggestFree(0, 0, 0, DWIDTH, DHEIGHT);
    if (free.biggest < ROOMINTERVAL) {
      break;
    } else {
      roomX = free.x + 1 + rnd(free.biggest - 1 - MINROOM);
      roomY = free.y + 1 + rnd(free.biggest - 1 - MINROOM);
      dungeon.dup(0, roomX, roomY, MINROOM, MINROOM);
      rooms.push({
        x: roomX,
        y: roomY,
        width: MINROOM,
        height: MINROOM,
        delete: "no"
      });
    }
  }

  var finalRooms = [];

  // Now we have seeds of growth in array rooms.
  // Lets try to expand seeds by moving their walls
  while (rooms.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
      // Determine the directions in which the room can grow 
      var dirs = [];
      if (rooms[i].x >= 2 && dungeon.freeRect(0, rooms[i].x - 2, rooms[i].y - 1, 1, rooms[i].height + 2)) {
        dirs.push('left');
      }
      if (rooms[i].x + rooms[i].width < DWIDTH - 1 && dungeon.freeRect(0, rooms[i].x + rooms[i].width + 1, rooms[i].y - 1, 1, rooms[i].height + 2)) {
        dirs.push('right');
      }
      if (rooms[i].y >= 2 && dungeon.freeRect(0, rooms[i].x - 1, rooms[i].y - 2, rooms[i].width + 2, 1)) {
        dirs.push('up');
      }
      if (rooms[i].y + rooms[i].height < DHEIGHT - 1 && dungeon.freeRect(0, rooms[i].x - 1, rooms[i].y + rooms[i].height + 1, rooms[i].width + 2, 1)) {
        dirs.push('down');
      }

      // Now expand room in random direction
      if (dirs.length > 0) {
        dirs.shuffle();
        if (dirs[0] == 'left') {
          dungeon.dup(0, rooms[i].x - 1, rooms[i].y, 1, rooms[i].height);
          rooms[i].x--;
          rooms[i].width++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'right') {
          dungeon.dup(0, rooms[i].x + rooms[i].width, rooms[i].y, 1, rooms[i].height);
          rooms[i].width++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'up') {
          dungeon.dup(0, rooms[i].x, rooms[i].y - 1, rooms[i].width, 1);
          rooms[i].y--;
          rooms[i].height++;
        }
        if (dirs[0] == 'down') {
          dungeon.dup(0, rooms[i].x, rooms[i].y + rooms[i].height, rooms[i].width, 1);
          rooms[i].height++;
        }
      } else {
        rooms[i].delete = "yes";
      }
      finalRooms = finalRooms.concat(rooms.filter(o => o.delete == "yes"));
      rooms = rooms.filter(o => o.delete == "no");
    }
  }

  var startRoom = finalRooms[0];
  startRoom.parentRoom = startRoom;
  connectToOtherRooms(dungeon, finalRooms, startRoom);
}

function connectToOtherRooms(dungeon, allRooms, currentRoom) {
  var adyacentRoom = connectToAdyacent(dungeon, allRooms, currentRoom);
  if (adyacentRoom) {
    connectToOtherRooms(dungeon, allRooms, adyacentRoom);
  } else {
    if (currentRoom.parentRoom == currentRoom) {
      return;
    } else {
      connectToOtherRooms(dungeon, allRooms, currentRoom.parentRoom);
    }
  }
}

// {x: 9, y: 12, width: 3, height: 6, delete: "yes"}

function connectToAdyacent(dungeon, allRooms, room) {
  var nonVisitedRooms = allRooms.filter(function(r) {
    return (r != room) && !r.parentRoom;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < nonVisitedRooms.length; i++) {
    var nonVisitedRoom = nonVisitedRooms[i];
    if (connectIfAdyacent(dungeon, room, nonVisitedRoom)) {
      nonVisitedRoom.parentRoom = room;
      return nonVisitedRoom;
    }
  }
}

function connectIfAdyacent(dungeon, room1, room2) {
  return connectIfOnTop(dungeon, room1, room2) ||
    connectIfOnTop(dungeon, room2, room1) ||
    connectIfOnRight(dungeon, room1, room2) ||
    connectIfOnRight(dungeon, room2, room1);
}

function connectIfOnTop(dungeon, roomBase, room) {
  var roomBase_x1 = roomBase.x - 1;
  var roomBase_x2 = roomBase.x + roomBase.width;
  var roomBase_y1 = roomBase.y - 1;
  //var roomBase_y2 = roomBase.y + roomBase.height;

  var room_x1 = room.x - 1;
  var room_x2 = room.x + room.width;
  var room_y1 = room.y - 1;
  var room_y2 = room.y + room.height;

  if (
    room_y2 == roomBase_y1 &&
    (room_x1 < (roomBase_x2 - 1)) &&
    (room_x2 > (roomBase_x1 + 1))
  ) {
    dungeon[Math.max(room_x1, roomBase_x1) + 1][room_y2] = 0;
    return true;
  }
}

function connectIfOnRight(dungeon, roomBase, room) {
  var roomBase_x1 = roomBase.x - 1;
  //var roomBase_x2 = roomBase.x + roomBase.width;
  var roomBase_y1 = roomBase.y - 1;
  var roomBase_y2 = roomBase.y + roomBase.height;

  var room_x1 = room.x - 1;
  var room_x2 = room.x + room.width;
  var room_y1 = room.y - 1;
  var room_y2 = room.y + room.height;

  if (
    room_x2 == roomBase_x1 &&
    (room_y1 < (roomBase_y2 - 1)) &&
    (room_y2 > (roomBase_y1 + 1))
  ) {
    dungeon[room_x2][Math.max(room_y1, roomBase_y1) + 1] = 0;
    return true;
  }
}


// rnd(4): returns 0, 1, 2 or 3
function rnd(ceil) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * ceil);
}


// Several instruments that I need to work with arrays
function arrayInstruments() {

  // Shuffles array in random order
  Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var j, temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      j = rnd(this.length);
      temp = this[i];
      this[i] = this[j];
      this[j] = temp;
    }
    return (this);
  }

  // Fills rectangle in 2D-array with filler
  Array.prototype.dup = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    for (var x = startX; x < startX + lengthX; x++) {
      if (!Array.isArray(this[x])) {
        this[x] = new Array();
      }
      for (var y = startY; y < startY + lengthY; y++) {
        this[x][y] = filler;
      }
    }
  }

  // Checks whether the specified area of the two-dimensional array is free of filler
  // If it is free, it returns true
  Array.prototype.freeRect = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    for (var x = startX; x < startX + lengthX; x++) {
      for (var y = startY; y < startY + lengthY; y++) {
        if (this[x][y] == filler) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }


  // Returns the coordinates of the largest empty square.
  // If there are several equally large empty squares, returns the coordinates of the random
  Array.prototype.biggestFree = function(filler, startX, startY, lengthX, lengthY) {
    var found = new Array();
    for (biggest = Math.min(lengthX, lengthY); biggest > 0; biggest--) {
      for (var x = startX; x <= startX + lengthX - biggest; x++) {
        for (var y = startY; y <= startY + lengthY - biggest; y++) {
          if (this.freeRect(filler, x, y, biggest, biggest)) {
            found.push({
              x: x,
              y: y
            });
          }
        }
      }
      if (found.length > 0) {
        found.shuffle();
        return {
          biggest: biggest,
          x: found[0].x,
          y: found[0].y
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Maze Generator</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding: 15;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="640" style="background: lightgrey"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I correctly understood the idea, we will get a tree of rooms, right?

Comment: we will get a tree of connected rooms (because step 322), the tree is nos useful by itself, it's only a structure to navigate all rooms without repeating.

Comment: I mean... navigate all rooms with a single path, which is what I understood as a requirement. This algorithm will not have cycles, If you want cycles, then you can connect some random adyacent rooms after all rooms are connected.

Comment: I`ll try to implement it.

Comment: You said "I will be very grateful for any idea or advice", you lied ^_^

Comment: I added a snippet (and JSfiddle link) with a working implementation.

Comment: I am impressed. I was just getting ready to start coding, and now I already have a ready-made piece!

Now, perhaps, I'll have to study your code and study the dungeon maps (on Google.Images) to understand how to divide the map into corridors and side rooms. I believe that the corridors should be combined into certain similarities of rings, so that the player does not have to return to the starting point of the "tree" every time, and from these corridors the short branches of the dead-end should depart.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark as solved or/and vote it if the answer helped you.

Comment: My zero starter rating does not allow me to vote - or perhaps my votes are not counted until then.

Should I mark the problem resolved now or after a while, when I will do (based on your code) an ideal generator and post it in the form of an add-on?

Comment: To mark the answer (not the question) as solved you need to click the check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png - Answers should be marked as solved if they resolve the original question. Future questions will be managed in new questions, do not update this one with new requirements, create new ones.